# How to count unique values in Pandas using string similarity techniques?

Tags: python, pandas, string

How to match names in column 'Company' and count unique ones with Pandas using string similarity techniques to match similar company names dynamically?

Data is like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Company": [
            "Aba",
            "aba electronics",
            "Marcipan",
            "Mars",
            "Mars coli",
            "Aba kon",
        ],
        "People": [
            "Aba2",
            "aba electronics3",
            "Marcipan4",
            "Mars5",
            "Mars coli6",
            "Aba kon7",
        ],
    }
)
```

Consider for example 'Aba', 'aba electronics', 'Aba con' are the same Company. Likewise 'Mars' and 'Mars coli' are the same company and should be counted once.

So far, my attempt to solve this problem:

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# Define function to match company names
def match_company_names(name, choices, cutoff):
    # Use fuzzywuzzy process.extractOne to get the best match
    match, score, idx = process.extractOne(
        name, choices, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio, score_cutoff=cutoff
    )
    if score >= cutoff:
        return match
    else:
        return None


# Define cutoff for matching
cutoff = 80

# Create a list of unique company names using fuzzy string matching
company_names = []
for name in data["Company"].unique():
    # First check if the name is already in the list
    if name in company_names:
        continue
    # Otherwise, try to match it with other names in the list
    matched_name = match_company_names(name, company_names, cutoff)
    if matched_name is not None:
        company_names[company_names.index(matched_name)] = name
    else:
        company_names.append(name)

# Count the number of occurrences of each unique company name
company_counts = {}
for name in company_names:
    company_counts[name] = sum(
        data["Company"].apply(lambda x: fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, name) >= cutoff)
    )

# Print the results
for name, count in company_counts.items():
    print(f"{name}: {count}")
```

Comment: Why do you make this `company_names[company_names.index(matched_name)]` ? It will raise an error if `matched_name` is not contained in `company_names`.

Comment: you are right but still not able to find solution to overall problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) from Python standard library's [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) module, and Pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts):

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

# Define a simple helper function
def ratio(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

# Iterate and evaluate each company name towards others
company_counts = data.apply(
    lambda x: [
        word.split(" ")[0].lower()
        for word in data["Company"]
        if ratio(x["Company"], word) > 0.8
    ][0],
    axis=1,
).value_counts()
```

Then:

```py
print(company_counts)
# Output
aba         3
mars        2
marcipan    1
```